# Angular 11 - How to replace the output of the api response in the html

Tags: angular, typescript, api

row.remarks has the output of 1 and 0. What I want to happen is that when the output is 0 I want to display it with the string "fail" and 1 is "passed" in the html. ` I'm using mat-table.

html

```
 <ng-container matColumnDef="remarks">
        <th class="font" mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef >Quiz Score</th>
        <td class="font" mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" >{{row.remarks}}</td>
      </ng-container>`
```

typescript

```
        interface IPost {
      id: number;
      quiz_id: number;
      quiz_title: string;
      difficulty: string;
      total_points: number;
      module_id: number;
      created_at: string;
      remarks: number;
      number_of_correct_answers: number;
      quiz_information: {
        quiz_title: string;
        difficulty: string;
        total_points: number;
      }
      users: {
        id: number;
        name: string;
    
      }

}



    getUserScoreByQuizID(quizID: number){

    this.dataService.getUserScoreByQuizID(quizID).subscribe(res=>{
      this.postsUser = res.UserScore;
      console.log(this.postsUser)

      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.postsUser);
      console.log(res);

    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;

    })
  }
```

Comment: You just want this ? `{{ row.remarks === 0 ? 'Fail' : 'Passed' }}`

Comment: 0 is actually already `falsy` so you write: `{{ row.remarks ? 'Passed' : 'Fail' }}`

Comment: {{ row.remarks ? 'Passed' : 'Fail' }} It is not reading if 1 == to passed and 0 == fail

Answer (score 1):

Please try with below code

```
this.dataService.getUserScoreByQuizID(quizID).subscribe(res => {
    res.UserScore.forEach(element => {
        element.remarks = element.remarks === 0 ? 'Fail' : 'Passed';
        this.postsUser.push(element);
    });
    console.log(this.postsUser)
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.postsUser);
    console.log(res);
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
})
```

Also change in your interface remark feild like below,

**remarks: number | string;**

Comment: In his interface, `remarks` is marked as a number, not a string :/

Comment: You can put in your interface like this remarks: number | string;

Comment: It's not working

Comment: Can you please create stackblitz?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it's solved using this {{ (row.remarks == 0) ? 'Fail' : 'Passed' }}

Answer (score 1):

There are many options like having a **custom pipe**, but simplest would be to use the `ternary operator` in the template:

```
{{ row.remarks ? 'Passed' : 'Fail' }}
```

Another option would be to have a method in your class:

**TS**

```
getRemarksMessage(remarks: number) {
  return remarks ? 'Passed' : 'Fail';
}
```

**HTML**

```html
{{ getRemarksMessage(row.remarks) }}
```

Comment: {{ row.remarks ? 'Passed' : 'Fail' }}
It is not reading if 1 == to passed and 0 == fail.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it's solved using this {{ (row.remarks == 0) ? 'Fail' : 'Passed' }}